# Use Java Graphics2D vs JOGL

Tags: java, graphics

I'm getting into learning Computer Graphics with Java. I was wondering, should I learn Java2D before learning JOGL, or should I just learn JOGL (which handles 3d graphics as well)? This (I hope) isn't an opinion based question in the sense that I'm looking for a correct path to follow. I guess, put another way, my question is: what is the point of having the Java Graphics 2D library if JOGL is around?

Note: my final goal is to be able to develop Graphics for business applications.

Comment: If you have no experience with computer graphics, I would highly recommend starting with `Graphics2D`, you can do quite a bit with it.  When you're ready to try more advanced ideas, including more advanced 2D and basic 3D, move onto the dedicated libraries - IMHO.  Graphics2D is the default implementation of Java/Swing's painting engine, it's standardised across platforms and works out the box, JOGL is dedicated binding to a particular rendering engine for a particular purpose.  Each has it's place and you need to decide, based on your requirements at the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "business applications". You're not talking about the "computer game business", are you? ;-)

Seriously: Nearly every question of the form "Should I use X or Y?" has the same kinds of answers:

1. "That depends on what *exactly* you want to do" and
2. the subjective ones.

The `Graphics2D` class is a rather high level abstraction, and with a few lines you can do your first custom painting operations. And they are intuitive. You want to draw a line with Graphics2D? Well, call `graphics.drawLine(0,0,100,100);`. You'll quickly have a feeling of success. The basic code to get started is conveniently summarized in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ , and with the knowledge from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html and some phantasy you can already achieve nice effects.

OpenGL is a different world. First of all its focus is **3D** graphics, and this is not "just a superset of 2D". While you technically *can* do 2D graphics with OpenGL as well, that's not what it was made for. It's much closer to the hardware, tailored for high-performance management of large 3D objects with powerful (and complex) rendering techniques. You want do draw a line with OpenGL? Well, if you want to do this with pure, modern (!) OpenGL, it will involve maybe 100 lines of code, including your own shader programs that are written in GLSL. And without a profound background certain fields of mathematics and graphics cards, and without a reading elaborate tutorials or books (like http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ ), you'll hardly be able to bring *anything* to the screen *at all*.

So to summarize it, concerning your actual question:

> what is the point of having the Java Graphics 2D library if JOGL is around?

If you want to create some 2D drawings, maybe some bar-, pie- or line charts, and maybe a few images, you simply would not use OpenGL due to its complexity. Java2D is part of the standard API, and it is tailored for things like this (although, of course, there are still different more specialized libraries for different purposes). If you want to do anything that goes beyond 2D, or employ some really sophisticated rendering effects, you'd have to use OpenGL.